# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'window'

Tags: python, pyqt5, eventhandler

I am a beginner with python I have created 2 interfaces with PyQt5
and I want to add event handler to a button (*infoButton*) so while is clicked it will open the second window.

The first window is 
**mainInterface.py** 
has a class

```
class Main_Form(object)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
     ## here is the main interface
      self.infoButton.clickd.connect(self.infoWindo)

     def __init__(self, window):
        super(Main_Form, self).__init__()
        self.windo = window

     def infoWindow(self, window):
        import description
        self.windo = description.Ui_Form()
        window.info()
        self.windo.show()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Main_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and I want to open **description.py**

```
class Ui_Form(object): 
    def setupUi2(self, Info):
     #here is the second interface
```

and the **error** is shown as

```
in <module> ui = Main_Form()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'window'
```

Comment: Well, yes; you've defined the initialization to require a `window` parameter, but then not supplied it. Why did you do this?

Comment: Actually I'm not very familiar with python interface, I'm using Qt to generate this code, and now I'm trying to open a new window with a button click, I found this way online but I would get this error as you can see.